# Python3: get sum of values of specific key in list of dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, list

I'm stumbled against a simple problem that I cannot figure out.
I have a list of objects saved in a json file. Once converted into Python they give me something like this:

```py
data = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 1},
    {"id": 3, "value": 5},
    {"id": 1, "value": 1},
    {"id": 1, "value": 2},
    {"id": 3, "value": 2},
    {"id": 1, "value": 3}
]
```

I'm trying to have only one object / dictionary per unique 'id'. In other words I'm trying to obtain the following result:

```py
[{"id": 1, "value": 9}, {"id": 2, "value": 1}, {"id": 3, "value": 7}]
```

Obviously, I could do it the long way around:

```py
foo = list(set([item["id"] for item in data]))

newList = []
for i in foo:
    bar = {"id": i, "value": 0}
    for x in data:
        if x['id'] == i:
            bar['value'] += x['value']

    newList.append(bar)
```

However I'm worried about this triple-nested loop which might slow down the process considerably with large datasets.

I'm familiar with `sum(d.values())` and I've seen the question on [collection's Counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764048/python-get-the-sum-of-values-of-a-key-in-list-of-dictionaries), but these do not work in my case.

Any ideas how the desired result can be obtained ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to the rescue!

First, create a dataframe from your data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

```
Output:
   id  value
0   1      3
1   2      1
2   3      5
3   1      1
4   1      2
5   3      2
6   1      3
```

Then, [group by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) id and [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

```
result = df.groupby("id").sum()
print(result)
```

```
Output:
    value
id       
1       9
2       1
3       7
```

And then convert this to the list like you want:

```
new_list = [{"id": elemid, "value": val.value} for elemid, val in result.iterrows()]
print(new_list)
# Output: [{'id': 1, 'value': 9}, {'id': 2, 'value': 1}, {'id': 3, 'value': 7}]
```

Alternatively, you could just improve your existing way:

```
data = [
    {"id": 1, "value": 3},
    {"id": 2, "value": 1},
    {"id": 3, "value": 5},
    {"id": 1, "value": 1},
    {"id": 1, "value": 2},
    {"id": 3, "value": 2},
    {"id": 1, "value": 3}
]

new_data = {}
for elem in data:
    elemid = elem["id"]
    value = elem["value"]
    new_data[elemid] = new_data.get(elemid, 0) + value

print(new_data)
# Output: {1: 9, 2: 1, 3: 7}
```

Then, convert this to the list like you want:

```
new_list = [{"id": key, "value": value} for key, value in new_data.items()]
print(new_list)
# Output: [{'id': 1, 'value': 9}, {'id': 2, 'value': 1}, {'id': 3, 'value': 7}]
```

Comment: pity it's closed for answering. here 's a one-liner: `sums = [{"id": i, "value": sum([d['value'] for d in data if d['id']==1])} for i in set([d['id'] for d in data])]`

Comment: @PeterM. you probably mean `d['id'] == i` instead of `d['id'] == 1`, but that's a worse solution than mine anyway because it's O(n^2). It's essentially the same as OP's

Comment: Yes Pranav. 1 should be i.